# How hide header menu except repository in ALFRESCO5

Tags: menu, hide, alfresco-share

I would Delete all voices in alfresco header menu excpet the repository voices how i can do there some template file to modify?

I tried with share-config.xml and share-config-custom.xml and nothing happened![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding menu from alfresco share you will need to extend header.For the same you need to have some knowledge regarding "DOJO".In alfresco 5.0 for headers ,It is highly dependent on dojo. I have created one module for which code is like below which is written inside *share-header.get.js*.Location where you need to put file is shown in image.

[image]

```
 var sitesMenu = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id",
    "HEADER_SITES_MENU");
 if (sitesMenu != null) {
    // Hide the site finder...
    if (user.isAdmin) {
    sitesMenu.config.showCreateSite = true;
    } 
 else {
    sitesMenu.config.showCreateSite = false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 4.2 method?

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-1/
http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-2/
http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-3/